# how to auto scroll bar change in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using Hscrollbar in vb.net. range is 0-50. Scroll bar Value is associated with text box.I want to auto scroll the scroll bar such as if I have text box value 50 then scroll bar should be at middle. how to do this in vb.net help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want the scrollbar to be half way if the textbox value is the same as the scrollbar's max value... But give this a go:

```
Try
    If CInt(TextBox1.Text) <= HScrollBar1.Maximum
    HScrollBar1.Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text) / 2
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```